# Using Oracle sys_refcursor returned stored procedure resultset in c# using entity framework

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure which returns select result set using sys_refcursor. Now I want to show these results in c# windows form application by Entity Framework (Model-First) function import feature, but EF Model Designer can not recognize return type of the procedure.

I have installed Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017. Also I have Created Model From Database and imported the stored procedure. My Oracle Version is 12.2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_EMPLOYEE_INFO(ID_EMPLOYEE IN NUMBER)
AS
EMP_INFO SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN 
    OPEN EMP_INFO
    FOR
    SELECT * FROM HR.EMPLOYEE WHERE ID=ID_EMPLOYEE;
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(EMP_INFO);
END;
```

So I want a complete instruction on how to map imported function return types correctly. Also I want to have a access to EMPLOYEE table's columns like  object properties (fields).

Comment: What version of EF?

Comment: EF 5, it seems that Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2017 does not support EF 6 because when I want to create model, the EF 6 option is disabled.

Comment: Try `db.Database.SqlQuery<Employee>("begin get_employee_info(:id); end;",23)`